# input whitespace from console in java

Tags: java, whitespace

If I input whitespace from console ,
console print this as a string . but, if I do it directly, it works correctly . why ? How can I print whitespace as a whitespace from console input?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input Whitespace :");
    String ss = sc.nextLine();//input whitespace from console 
    String st ="\n \t";//input whitespace directly 
    System.out.println("print whitespace direcly :"+st+"print whitespace from console : "+ss);

}
```

input : Input Whitespace :\n \t

output : print whitespace direcly :
    print whitespace from console : \n \t

Comment: I am calling this directly :  String st ="\n \t";

Comment: Your input of `\n` isn't a valid whitespace, it is just a single backslash and an "n" without any meaning. The same applies to your input `\t`.

Comment: If it is not valid whitespace, how can I input valid whitespace from console ?

Comment: Your input will be `\\n` (since the entered backslash will be escaped) and you need to "convert" it. The linked duplicate explains how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you, for your helping @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now it will work :

```
    ss=ss.replace("\n", "\\n");
    ss=ss.replace("\t", "\\t");
    ss=ss.replace("\f", "\\f");
    ss=ss.replace("\r", "\\r");
    ss=ss.replace("\\n", "\n");
    ss=ss.replace("\\t", "\t");
    ss=ss.replace("\\f", "\f");
    ss=ss.replace("\\r", "\r");
```

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the first four lines is? `ss` doesn't contain these whitespaces, so you don't need to replace them.

Comment: As I want to use \n,\t,\f,\r as a whitespace . So, I have to do this. Else, whitespace(new line , tab ) is not printing only \n \t \r \f are printing.

Comment: @tom . I think you can't understand my problem.

Comment: *"I think you can't understand my problem"* No, you don't understand what you're doing there. The first four lines are useless when you want to convert manually entered `\n` (or the whitespace representations) strings. You only need the latter four `replace` calls.